# Использование content с svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Необходимо отображать svg в блоке с определённым классом. Ранее никогда такого не делал. Спасибо.

Мой неработающий вариант:

```
.paid:after {
    content: url('money-icon.svg');
}
```

Comment: вообще всё работает таким образом - что конкретно не получилось ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем здесь иконка с моего сервера не отображается но на codepen работает: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/zYORYzb

```css
.icon{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative; 
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.icon:after{
 content:url(http://maximumlensky.0fees.us/icon.svg);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```